# how to access an in memory variable of a java program, while it is running?

Tags: java, global-variables, memory-access

> i am running a java *crawler* program in eclipse. I have not enabled a debugger.

I am printing some *variables* after the crawling is complete. but the crawler takes a lot of *time* to complete so i don't know when these variables will be printed.

i want to access these variables while the *crawler is running* and i dont want to stop it because it is already running for a while. How do i access these variables? thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking how to access a field?  I assume since you have written a web crawler you must have used fields before.

Comment: Umm, use the debugger, or put in some println statements?

Comment: Edit the code so the variables are printed when you have them rather than after? There's really not much else to say with what you've asked.

Comment: If you have a Java program that's already running, that you can't stop or edit, you're completely out of luck.

Comment: sorry guys, i didnt refresh page. i thought no one was commenting.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: no i am not talking about field. i am doing a college project. In which i have to answer the question how many unique URLs in a domain? so i am storing this info in a hashtable variable while running the crawler. how to access this variable.

Comment: To "access" the variable you have basically two choices:  Use the debugger facilities, or write the data to a file or database and read it in another program.  But it's easy to add print statements that will write out the data at intervals, either based on a timer or based on loop counts, etc.

Comment: @raghu I am still lost.  I assume your HashTable is in a variable somewhere (or the GC would discard it)  To access it, you need a reference to it and you can get a value or look at the whole collection. Are you trying to access it without writing any code or some assumption I am missing?

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes, the program has been running for 1.5 day. i dont want to stop now and use debugger or println etc.

Comment: public class MyCrawler extends WebCrawler {
      private static Hashtable<String, Integer> subDomains;
      public main(){
            while(1){
                  crawl(); //edits subDomain
            }
      }
      public printsubdomain(){   //printsubdomain may not be called
      }                          //how do i access variable subDomain
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the program has been running for 1.5 day. i dont want to stop now and use debugger or println

If you cannot change the code of a running process (which is an important detail for a developer to forget to mention) your only option is to trigger a heap dump using VisualVM or the like. This will give you the entire JVM but in it will be your HashTable.

Comment: i think this might be useful. could you please point me to a link where i can do this?thanks

Comment: You cannot to the process using VisualVM and perform a heap dump using a button on one of the tabs. I suggest you trigger a GC first to minimise the size of the heap and it will be easier to load.  This should trigger VisualVM to ask you if you want to load it. I suggest you practice on a smaller program first.  It can have trouble loading heaps much larger than 1 GB.

Comment: i am sorry, i am lost. i think this crawler's heap is around 800mb. i am kind of a newbie. i donno what GC is and also i never used visualvm.

Comment: I don't think you will get a simpler explanation as you are attempting to do something which most profession experts would never have done. If you think running VisualVM is difficult, searching for a HashTable in 800 MB of data and understanding what it means from it's internal data structure is going to be far, far more advanced. If you had 10 years experience debugging Java programs I would still say you should expect it to be tricky.

Comment: i don't think it is difficult, but yeah i never ran it. anyways thanks for the info.

Comment: Imagine you have to jump onto a speeding train, if that is not hard enough, it left 1.5 days ago, you don't where it is and you don't know what a train looks like. It's something only stunt men in movies do (except they have all the information they need)  I am trying to impress on you why it is critical for a program to log all important information before it starts.  It's like catching a stationary train which is still at the station at the start of the line with helpful people to guide you.